# Using $.each on JSON object created from MySQL COUNT()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I have been using JSON objects encoded in PHP from my MySQL database in many places with no problems. I am now trying to create one from a resultset using COUNT(column) in the syntax and I think it is causing a the problem but I have no idea how to fix it.

My JS looks like this...

```
createTeacherStatsTab = function(){
    $('#main').append('<div id="teacherStatsTab></div>"');
    $.getJSON("php/countMarkingPerTeacher.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('#teacherStatsTab').append(val.teacher + ' : ' + val.count(teacher));
        });
    });
}
```

And my PHP looks like this...

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT teacher, COUNT(teacher) 
FROM Assessment
GROUP BY teacher
ORDER BY COUNT(teacher) DESC
");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

The data that come back looks like this...

```
[
{
teacher: "SDe",
COUNT(teacher): "413"
},
{
teacher: "OJe",
COUNT(teacher): "297"
},
{
teacher: "AMi",
COUNT(teacher): "257"
},
{
teacher: "ASt",
COUNT(teacher): "218"
},
{
teacher: "VJa",
COUNT(teacher): "194"
},
{
teacher: "SLa",
COUNT(teacher): "125"
},
{
teacher: "MCr",
COUNT(teacher): "99"
}
]
```

It feels like this is probably something to do with the GROUP BY stripping ID's or something?

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JS interprets your property access as a function call because of the parenthesis:

```
val.count(teacher)
```

The most simple solution i guess is to give your `COUNT()` result an alias name:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT 
  teacher, 
  COUNT(teacher) AS teacher_count
FROM Assessment
GROUP BY teacher
ORDER BY COUNT(teacher) DESC
");
```

And access it like:

```
$('#teacherStatsTab').append(val.teacher + ' : ' + val.teacher_count);
```

Comment: This has fixed it, I knew it was going to be something in the SQL syntax but it's my weakest area. I also realised that it was probably the parenthesis in the COUNT() that was causing a problem but i'd gone round in circles a few times and I'd lsot sight of it all. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the object does not allow parenthesis on its properties, so when you call `val.count(teacher)` you are trying to call the inexisting `count` method of the `val` object. Try calling `val["count(teacher)"]` instead, or just changing the property name.

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning that if the query was slightly changed to something like `SELECT teacher, COUNT(teacher) as teacherCount`, then the whole problem goes away :) [edit - whoops.. you did.. sorry]

Comment: This makes sense but I have accepted the other answer as it was slightly clearer about how to fix it, as was the comment above this by @Stephen. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Overall, the problem is that `json_encode` appears to be returning invalid JSON. Your object keys contain `(` and `)` which are invalid characters for object keys (unless they're contained in a string like in the example below).

```
[{
    "teacher": "SDe",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "413"
}, {
    "teacher": "OJe",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "297"
}, {
    "teacher": "AMi",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "257"
}, {
    "teacher": "ASt",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "218"
}, {
    "teacher": "VJa",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "194"
}, {
    "teacher": "SLa",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "125"
}, {
    "teacher": "MCr",
    "COUNT(teacher)": "99"
}]
```

The easiest fix is to alias your `COUNT(teacher)` column:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT teacher, COUNT(teacher) AS count
FROM Assessment
GROUP BY teacher
ORDER BY COUNT(teacher) DESC
");
```

This should render your JSON as

```
[{
    teacher: "SDe",
    count: "413"
}, {
    teacher: "OJe",
    count: "297"
}, {
    teacher: "AMi",
    count: "257"
}, {
    teacher: "ASt",
    count: "218"
}, {
    teacher: "VJa",
    count: "194"
}, {
    teacher: "SLa",
    count: "125"
}, {
    teacher: "MCr",
    count: "99"
}]
```

which is valid JSON (without having to stringificate the keys) and your existing function should work fine (after changing `val.count(teacher)` to `val.count`):

```
createTeacherStatsTab = function () {
    $('#main').append('<div id="teacherStatsTab></div>"');
    $.getJSON("php/countMarkingPerTeacher.php", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            $('#teacherStatsTab').append(val.teacher + ' : ' + val.count);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I have already accepted another answer but this is very clearly explained. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -2):

you are getting array of json.so you have to get zeroth element and than you have to iterate over it so you have to do  in this way

```
$.getJSON("php/countMarkingPerTeacher.php", function(data) {
    var myData = data[0];
    $.each(myData, function(key, val) {
        $('#teacherStatsTab').append(val.teacher + ' : ' + val.count(teacher));
    });
});
```

if your json was in this format than your code would have worked

```
{
teacher: "SDe",
COUNT(teacher): "413"
},
{
teacher: "OJe",
COUNT(teacher): "297"
},
{
teacher: "AMi",
COUNT(teacher): "257"
},
{
teacher: "ASt",
COUNT(teacher): "218"
},
{
teacher: "VJa",
COUNT(teacher): "194"
}
```

Comment: val.count isn't going to be a function here - that'll end up just erroring out. besides that, the data is already an array - doing something like data[0] will just grab the first element which is going to be {teacher: "SDe", COUNT(teacher): "413")